# Using Swift library in Xamarin

Tags: swift, xamarin, binding

The article https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/ mentions how a native library written using Objective-C can be used in Xamarin. 
Is there any documentation available for doing the same with a native framework written in Swift? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/embedded_frameworks/ talks about using embedded frameworks but it does not say anything about swift. Does the same thing work?

Comment: Swift does not support creating static `.a` libraries, it only supports Framework creation. The only way that I currently know of is to create an ObjC static library and expose your Swift Framework via ObjC-based functions and then you can bind that to C#.

Comment: @SushiHangover - if a project has any swift reference,then it can not be translated into .a library right ! but if it uses swift framework then its not the problem we can convert it into .a library.Correct me If I am wrong !If you have any working sample hosted in Github or something kindly consider sharing it

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: @SushiHangover - you have mentioned we can import a swift framework and we can expose Swift APIs through Objective C... and so we can get .a static library and which will be used for binding...Is my understanding right ?

Answer (score 4):

Binding Swift libraries is not officially supported, but you can find a documentation on how to do it:

https://medium.com/@Flash3001/binding-swift-libraries-xamarin-ios-ff32adbc7c76

Comment: Excellent one ! You are the MVP :) !

Comment: Broken link, can you post it directly?

Comment: I've saved it when they announced the shutdown, just posted it on Medium.

Comment: For those who are struggling with this, I came up with a tool that simplifies the process that @LucasTeixeira explains in his post.
https://github.com/kikettas/xamapod

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to reopen a death thread, but binding Swift library is now officially supported by Xamarin.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/walkthrough

The procedure is very similar than the one needed to bind Objective-C libraries. In fact, Swift is compatible only with Swift, and a Swift framework to be accessible to Objective-C or Xamarin needs to export Objective-C headers.