# How do I bind a swift based .Framework or Pod to Xamarin?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie

I'm trying to bind this [Folding Cell](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell) to an Xamarin project but don't see the *.a file mentioned [in these directions.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/examples/cocoapod/)

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
sharpie pod init ios FoldingCell
sharpie pod bind
```

As indicated at the bottom of the page, I should [follow these directions to make a binding project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/#Create_a_Xamarin.iOS_Binding_Project), but the directions require the `*.a` file.

Since I have the source of the FoldingCell framework, I know I can likely make the changes needed.

(Disclaimer, all of my iOS work is with Xamarin, not XCode)

Comment: Update - I had the same missing *.a file with this project by the same author: https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MonoTouch binding from a .framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586342/how-to-create-a-monotouch-binding-from-a-framework)

Answer (score 5):

Binding Swift libraries is not officially supported, but you can find a documentation on how to do it:

https://medium.com/@Flash3001/binding-swift-libraries-xamarin-ios-ff32adbc7c76

Same answer is given in: [Using Swift library in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404386/using-swift-library-in-xamarin/39491888#39491888)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `FoldingCell` is a [swift library](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell/blob/master/FoldingCell/FoldingCell/FoldingCell/FoldingCell.swift) and Xamarin.iOS does not have built in support for that yet. Currently (as June 2016) you have two options:

1. Port [FoldingCell.swift](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell/blob/master/FoldingCell/FoldingCell/FoldingCell/FoldingCell.swift) to C# or F#
2. Create an ObjC framework to bridge swift and bind that, unfortunately I do not have a tutorial on how to do that but you can use your favourite search engine to look on how to bridge Objective-C and Swift. Note that this option is iOS 8+.

Hope this gets you in the right direction.