# How to do a Xamarin.iOS Folding Cell

Tags: xamarin.ios, cell, folding

I have found swift code and a plugin to do the a Folding Cell. However, is there any code or plugin to do this in Xamarin.iOS. This is what i found https://github.com/0ber/Folding-cell-programmatically. There is a plugin available for Android Xam.Plugins.Android.FoldingCell but i can't find anything for Xamarin.iOS. Would really appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

i am not familiar with Xamarin, but you can try using sharpie to convert the ios code to Xamarin bindings

You can refer to this post:
[Using Swift library in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404386/using-swift-library-in-xamarin/39491888#39491888)